# Windows 7 Virtual PC BSOD

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, virtual-machines

I have a problem with Win7 & VirtualPC - every time I start up a virtual machine, it appears to start fine, and then about 10 seconds into the boot process, my laptop either BSOD's or just hangs.

I have a Dell Inspiron 1721 notebook that i've been running the x86 version of Win7 on - and have had the issue with both build 7000 & 7100.  I also have the issue with the Windows Virtual PC beta and with the Virtual PC 2007 product.

I've tried to use WinDBG to get what I can out of the minidump files - but i'm not sure if I have that set up correctly.  Here's what I get from that...

CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (101)
An expected clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor in an
MP system within the allocated interval. This indicates that the specified
processor is hung and not processing interrupts.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000061, Clock interrupt time out interval in nominal clock ticks.
Arg2: 00000000, 0.
Arg3: 807c4120, The PRCB address of the hung processor.
Arg4: 00000001, 0.

--Anyone know what I can look at to correct this?  As a developer, i REALLY miss my virtual PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was/is a known issue on Windows Server 2008 Beta, so it may be related.

Try upgrading your BIOS, or just wait for a fix from Microsoft.

Comment: I've checked the BIOS, there is no newer version.  Do you know of there are any workarounds?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a bug in Intel Core i-7 (or other processors in the same family).

I had the exact same problem (running Windows Server 2008 R2 and Hyper-V). Whenever I ran an instance of a virtual machine, it crashed after a few minutes.

Fortunately, there is a hotfix available for this, see this [KB-article](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=975530)

After applying this hotfix, the problem goes away.